# Django ModelForm does not validate image file upload

Tags: django, forms, file-upload

I have a ModelForm with one image field as follows:

```
class ProfilePhotoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePhoto
        fields = ["image"]
```

I have a View that uses the ModelForm as follows:

```
class ProfileView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.first()
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        photo_form = ProfilePhotoForm(instance=profile)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        return render(request, "edit_profile.html", {"photo_form": photo_form, "profile_form": profile_form })

    def post(self, request):    
        if 'picture' in self.request.POST:
            photo_form = ProfilePhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='photo_form')
            import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
            if photo_form.is_valid():
                image = photo_form.cleaned_data['image']
                user = User.objects.first()
                profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
                profile_photo = ProfilePhoto.objects.get(profile=profile)
                if profile_photo:
                    profile_photo.delete()
                ProfilePhoto.objects.create(profile=profile, image=image)
        elif 'profile' in self.request.POST:
            profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='profile_form')
            if profile_form.is_valid():
                profile_form.save()
        return render(request, "edit_profile.html", {})
```

The template that is rendered with the GET request of the view is as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">   
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="5sY3rFOqYjJTAkOUKVcoAkIthA10RbCc">
        <input class="form-control margin10" id="id_image" name="image" placeholder="Image" type="file">
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-primary margin10" id="register" type="submit" name="picture" value="Upload Profile Picture">
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="5sY3rFOqYjJTAkOUKVcoAkIthA10RbCc">
        <input class="form-control margin10" id="id_display_name" maxlength="50" name="display_name" placeholder="Display name" type="text" value="Kent Shikama">
        <textarea class="form-control margin10" cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" placeholder="Description" rows="10">A CS major taking CS133</textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-primary margin10" id="register" type="submit" name="profile" value="Change Profile">
    </form>
</div>
```

In the ProfileView class I have placed a ipdb debug stop. Here is some potentially relevant output:

```
ipdb> photo_form.data
<QueryDict: {'picture': ['Upload Profile Picture'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['5sY3rFOqYjJTAkOUKVdoAkIthA10RbCc']}>
ipdb> photo_form.files
<MultiValueDict: {'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: self_square.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
ipdb> photo_form.errors
{'image': ['This field is required.']}
```

I have searched up a lot of related questions: most of them say to double check that request.FILES has been passed into the form and that the enctype is set. The fact that photo_form.files returns a InMemoryUploadedFile seems to signify that the image has indeed been uploaded. Hence, I'm confused as to why the form is not validating. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the name combined with the prefix 'photo_form-image' did not match the HTML input name of 'image'

I discovered this while stepping through the ipdb:

```
ipdb> l
    335 
--> 336     def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    337         "File widgets take data from FILES, not POST"
    338         return files.get(name, None)
    339 
ipdb> name
'photo_form-image'
ipdb> files.get(name)
ipdb> files.get('image')
<InMemoryUploadedFile: self_square.jpg (image/jpeg)>
```